# can connect to api using Javascript ajax but not php cURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I am trying to use an api for my php application. I am able to connect the api using javascript with the following code but when I use cUrl, the server returns "Failed to connect to api.xxxx.com port 8012 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server." What could be the reason?

```
var arr1 = {
 date: $("#traveldate").val().split("-").reverse().join("-"),
 from: $("#from").val(),
 to: $("#to").val(),
 userName: "adventure",
 token: "U2FsdGVkX19hyFXiE1f7Q3O9haGk/XFP/g5tQL3VDJujLVCBURxN+RVhGxry64/KJA==",
};
$.ajax(
 {
     url: "http://api.dev.xxxxxx.com:8012/getTripData",
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify(arr1),
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(msg) {
     console.log(msg);
     },
     error: function(){
         console.log("error");
     }
  });
```

The above code works fine

```
$url = 'http://api.dev.xxxx.com:8012/getTripData';
$data = array(
 "date"=>"20-08-2023",
 "from"=>"Port Blair",
 "to"=>"Swaraj Dweep",
 "userName"=>"adventure",
 "token"=>"U2FsdGVkX19hyFXiE1f7Q3O9haGk/XFP/g5tQL3VDJujLVCBURxN+RVhGxry64/KJA==",
);
               
$encodedData = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($url);
$data_string = urlencode(json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
if (isset($error_msg)) {
    print_r($error_msg);
}
print_r($result);
```

This doesn't work. Please help

Comment: Why port 8012? Perhaps the curl does not need that?

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
var_dump($stderr);
```

Comment: can you connect to ANYTHING from php? if you change out the url with `$url = "https://example.org";` what do you get?

Comment: usually means a firewall issue, either your php runner or your target server is running an IP whitelist/blacklist blocking your php runner from communicating with `api.dev.xxxx.com`

Comment: string(263) "* processing: https://api.gonautika.com:8012/getTripData * Trying 139.59.91.40:8012... * connect to 139.59.91.40 port 8012 failed: Connection refused * Failed to connect to api.gonautika.com port 8012 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server * Closing connection "

Comment: it works with https://example.org

Comment: Probably that port is blocked outgoing on the machine where the php is running. Check the firewall rules.

Comment: Yes, It the firewall is blocking port 8012, but the api provider is using this port. It's a shared webhosting, what can I do?

Comment: You can ask the webhost to unblock it. If they won't, you can find a new webhost.